# Fedora V-Play on Qt: cannot find libraries

Tags: c++, qt, fedora, v-play

I am new for VPlay, after I installed V-Play with Qt and I wrote a simple project, and I got error message after compiling:

```
error: cannot find -lpulse-mainloop-glib
error: cannot find -lpulse
error: cannot find -lglib-2.0
```

But I tried:

```
sudo dnf install pulseaudio-libs
sudo dnf install glibs2
```

It shows that I already installed these libraries, but the result of compiling still the same.
What packages I should install now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing `pulseaudio-libs-devel` and `glib2-devel`.